# Documents in MongoDB where last n sub-array elements contain a value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Consider this set of data in MongoDB...

```js
{
_id: 1,
name: "Johnny",
properties: [
    {
        type: "A",
        value: 257,
        date: "4/1/2014"
    },
    {
        type: "A",
        value: 200,
        date: "4/2/2014"
    },
    {
        type: "B",
        value: 301,
        date: "4/3/2014"
    },
    ...]
}
```

What is the proper way to query the the documents in which the one (or more of) last two "properties" elements have a value > x, or one (or more of) the last two "properties" elements of type "A" have a value > x?

Comment: Have you tried the aggregation framework? What queries have you tried and what's not working?

Comment: Hi. I've looked at the aggregation framework documentation, and the examples all seem to be geared toward - aggregation, sums, counts, etc. That's not what I'm looking for. It also would seem that grouping wouldn't apply - because I'm not trying to aggregate data - I'm simply trying to identify documents based on recent array elements within a nested array. Is there a specific feature set within aggregation that I should be looking at? I am new to NoSQL - just trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: What you need is the [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) query operator to match more than one component within an array.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the case - I'm not trying to match two components in an array - I'm trying to do an OR operator on a number of elements within an array. If I were simply matching Type = "A" and Value > 200, I think you would be correct. But, I'm trying to do that comparison on the latest two (or more) elements of the array only.

Comment: The reason I mentioned using aggregation is that it might get you close to your requirements. Your document structure is not suited well to the query you want in MongoDb.

Comment: @WiredPrairie - Thanks. Good to know. I'm certainly not tied to this design at this point - it's simply a sample of what I need to do. How would you design the document to get where I want to go. This is 15 years of RDBMS design rearing its ugly head.

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you had additional details in what you were trying to accomplish. The statement that I don't understand in particular is the "...one (or more of) the last...". I usually suggest sort of "denormalizing" in RDBMS terms and having a bit of duplicate data. Like having the "last two" be specific and easily queried fields that are directly stored on the document, rather than buried in an array of unknown length.

Comment: Specifically, I am storing students' test scores in a document. I need to have a historical view, but also the ability to look at the last two (or three, four, whatever) to see if they fall below a certain threshold. This is a commercial system, with multiple schools tracking and using different tests - so I cannot really make any assumptions in the query itself. Some schools will only want to look at the most recent test. Some will want to look at the last 5. They will not be looking at the same tests... So, it must be fairly generic. Helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, the aggregation framework is for a lot more than simply "aggregating" values, so you can take advantage of the various [pipeline operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/operators/) to do very advanced things that cannot be achieved simply using [**`.find()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Match documents that "could" meet the conditions to narrow down
    { "$match": {
        "properties": { "$elemMatch": {
            "type": "A", "value": { "$gt": 200 }
        }}
    }},

    // Keep a copy of the document for later with an array copy
    { "$project": {
        "_id": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "name": "$name",
            "properties": "$properties" 
        },
        "properties": 1
    }},

    // Unwind the array to "de-normalize"
    { "$unwind": "$properties" },

    // Get the "last" element of the array and copy the existing one
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "properties": { "$last": "$_id.properties" },
        "last": { "$last": "$properties" },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},

    // Unwind the copy again
    { "$unwind": "$properties" },

    // Project to mark the element you already have
    { "$project": {
          "properties": 1,
          "last": 1,
          "count": 1,
          "seen": { "$eq": [ "$properties", "$last" ] }
    }},

    // Match again, being careful to keep any array with one element only
    // This gets rid of the element you already kept
    { "$match": { 
        "$or": [
            { "seen": false },
            { "seen": true, "count": 1 }
        ]
    }},

    // Group to get the second last element as "next"
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "last": { "$last": "$last" },
        "next": { "$last": "$properties" }
    }},

    // Then match to see if either of those elements fits
    { "$match": {
        "$or": [
            { "last.type": "A", "last.value": { "$gt": 200 } },
            { "next.type": "A", "next.value": { "$gt": 200 } }
        ]
    }},

    // Finally restore your matching documents
    { "$project": {
        "_id": "$_id._id",
        "name": "$_id.name",
        "properties": "$_id.properties"
    }}

])
```

Running through that in a bit more detail:

- The first [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) usage is to make sure you are only working on documents that can "possibly" match your extended conditions. Always a good idea to optimize like this.
- The next stage is to [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) since you likely want to keep the original document detail and you are at least going to need the array again in order to get the second last element.
- The next stages make use of [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) in order to break the array into individual documents which is then followed by [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) which is used to find the last item on the document `_id` boundary. This is actually the last item in the array. Plus you keep a count of the array elements.
- So then after using [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) again on the original array content, the usage of [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) again adds a "seen" field to the document indicating via the use of the $eq operator whether or not the document from the original is actually the one that was previously keep as the "last" element.
- After that stage you again issue a [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) in order to filter that last document from the result, but also making sure in the condition that you are not removing anything that originally matched where the array length is actually 1.
- From here you want to [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) again in order to get the "second last" element from the array (or indeed the same "last" element where there was only one.
- The final steps are simply to [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) where either of those last two elements meets the conditions, and then finally [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) the document in it's original form.

So while that is fairly involved and of course increases in complexity by the number of items you want to test at the end of the array it can be done, and shows how aggregate is very suited to the problem.

Where possible it is the best approach as invoking the JavaScript interpreter will convey an overhead compared to the native code used by aggregate.

Using mapReduce would remove the code complexity for taking the last two possible elements (or more) but it will invoke the JavaScript interpreter by nature and will therefore run much more slowly.

---

For the record, since the sample in the question would **not** be a match, here is some data that will match the last two documents, one of which only has one element in the array:

```js
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "name" : "Johnny",
    "properties" : [
            {
                    "type" : "A",
                    "value" : 257,
                    "date" : "4/1/2014"
            },
            {
                    "type" : "A",
                    "value" : 200,
                    "date" : "4/2/2014"
            },
            {
                    "type" : "B",
                    "value" : 301,
                    "date" : "4/3/2014"
            }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "name" : "Ace",
    "properties" : [
            {
                    "type" : "A",
                    "value" : 257,
                    "date" : "4/1/2014"
            },
            {
                    "type" : "B",
                    "value" : 200,
                    "date" : "4/2/2014"
            },
            {
                    "type" : "B",
                    "value" : 301,
                    "date" : "4/3/2014"
            }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "name" : "Bo",
    "properties" : [
            {
                    "type" : "A",
                    "value" : 257,
                    "date" : "4/1/2014"
            }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "name" : "Sue",
    "properties" : [
            {
                    "type" : "A",
                    "value" : 257,
                    "date" : "4/1/2014"
            },
            {
                    "type" : "A",
                    "value" : 240,
                    "date" : "4/2/2014"
            },
            {
                    "type" : "B",
                    "value" : 301,
                    "date" : "4/3/2014"
            }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can stomach modifying your insertion method try as follows;

Change your updates to push the following:

```
doc = { type : "A", "value" : 123, "date" : new Date() }
db.foo.update( {_id:1}, { "$push" : { "properties" : { "$each" : [ doc ], "$sort" : { date : -1} } } } )
```

This will give you an array of documents sorted in descending order by time, making the "most recent" document first.

You can now use the standard MongoDB dot notation to query against the [0, 1, etc elements of your properties array](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-a-specific-element-of-an-array), which represent the most recent additions logically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a $where clause? Not the most efficient but I think it should get you what you want. For instance, if you wanted every document that had either the last two properties elements value field greater than 200 you could try:

```
db.collection.find({properties:{$exists:true},
                    $where: "(this.properties[this.properties.length-1].value > 200)||
                             (this.properties[this.properties.length-2].value > 200)"});
```

This needs some work for edge cases (array < 2 members for example) and more complex queries (by the "type" field too) but should get you started.

Comment: This might work - I'll play with it. I think it's going to boil down to a combination of aggregates and $elemMatch - and probably $where. The "edge" case is probably not going to be edge - but the typical use.

Comment: @du8die While it does compare the last two elements of an array, and with the noted limitations, usage of JavaScript for this sort of comparison is never a very performant solution and should be avoided where another method exists. Such as it does.